# Android unzip file without double space needed

Tags: android, zip, unzip

In my Android application user has to download zip file which contains 1000 files (about 700MB).

I have to unzip this file, but I don't wan't to take next 700MB for unzipping, because user would need to have free 1400MB disk space.

Example:

1. User downloads zip file - total space taken 700MB
2. User unpack szip file - total space taken 1400MB
3. Application deletes .zip file - total space taken 700MB

How not to take next 700 MB while unpacking?

Comment: Have you tried zipinputstream in android? I'm not sure but maybe you could delete the blocks after you read.

Comment: I tried but I failed. Every solution that I found bases on creating temp file